# Counting unique rows in Google sheets with row output plus count

Tags: google-sheets

How do you COUNT the number of unique rows in Google Sheets?
I have searched the knowledge base here but no luck.

My table looks like this :

```
Inst       vCPU    RAM  OS
t2.large    2       8   Windows
t2.large    2       8   Windows
t2.medium   2       4   Windows
t2.small    1       2   RHEL
t2.micro    1       1   Linux
t2.micro    1       1   Linux
```

I would like an output like this:

```
Count  Inst       vCPU    RAM   OS
2      t2.large     2       8   Windows
1      t2.medium    2       4   Windows
1       t2.small    1       2   RHEL
2       t2.micro    1       1   Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

This will be the easiest method.

```
=QUERY (A1:D7,"Select Count (A),A,avg(B),avg(C), max (D) group by A")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish something like this. One suggestion is to use the [`=UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) function to output the unique rows, and the [`=COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en) function to count each instance.

Let's say you have your input table in cells `A2:D8`. Position the cursor in the cell where you want the output table, let's say `F2`, and enter the formula `=UNIQUE(A2:D)`. This outputs the input data, leaving out duplicates.

Position the cursor to the right of the output table, in cell `J3`. In the first data row, enter the formula `=COUNTIFS(A$3:A; "=" & F3; B$3:B; "=" & G3; C$3:C; "=" & H3; D$3:D; "=" & I3)`.
This counts rows from the input table, which satisfies the criteria given: The `A` cell value must equal the value of cell `F3`, the `B` cell must equal `G3` and so on. The result is the number of rows of the input table that equals the (duplicate-filtered) output table.
Drag this formula down, to cover the rest of the rows.

I have set up [an example spreadsheet to demonstrate](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PadYj-VkmdMzcw7s7u85yW96OFn0GbhFSkzyYzB962k/edit?usp=sharing), feel free to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

With a helper column to string together the columns 'conventional' processing is possible with simple formulae:

[image: WA109439 example]

A2: `=I2&"|"&J2&"|"&K2&"|"&L2`
B2: `=unique(A2:A)`
C2: `=countif(A2:A,B2)`
D2: `=split(B2:B,"|")`

Copied down to suit as necessary.

[UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)
[COUNT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093620)
[SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)